# Use create-react-app without install modules

Tags: create-react-app

How can I use `create-react-app` without installing modules? I just want to get source code and skip `npm i` phase because it's taking time. Is there any `command-line` flag to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code for the base create-react-app template:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/cra-template/template

You can download the files directly from this link without installing any `node-modules`:

https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/cra-template/template

Comment: Thanks for answers my question. But what I want is use `create-react-app`, not using `git` to clone source code.

Comment: @namgold I checked what you can do with `create-react-app` and it doesn't seem like they have a command-line flag like you wanted.